# sched_setscheduler error (EPERM) after installing libpam-systemd

Tags: linux, pam, ubuntu-15.04

Just trying to set the sched priority to max with `SCHED_FIFO` policy. This code started throwing error after I installed libpam-systemd.

**EDIT**: Boils down to the two questions below, put them as clear as I can.

STRACE:

> sched_setscheduler(564, SCHED_FIFO, { 99 }) = -1 EPERM (Operation not
>   permitted)

```
param.sched_priority = sched_get_priority_max(SCHED_FIFO);
printf("priority %d \n", param.sched_priority);

ret1 = sched_setscheduler(getpid(), SCHED_FIFO, &param);
printf("sched_setscheduler ret %d \n", ret1);
if(ret1 == -1){
    perror("sched_setscheduler");
    goto fail;
}
```

**QUESTION**: Why should a root user get EPERM ?

Also tried to set below in `/etc/security/limits.conf` without any luck.

```
root   soft   rtprio       99    
root   hard   rtprio       99
```

**FROM KENREL CONFIG FILE**

```
#CONFIG_SCHED_AUTOGROUP is not set
CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED=y
CONFIG_FAIR_GROUP_SCHED=y
CONFIG_CFS_BANDWIDTH=y
CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED=y
CONFIG_GENERIC_SCHED_CLOCK=y
CONFIG_CGROUPS=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_CGROUP_FREEZER=y
```

**UPDATE**
Error in kernel code in file `linux/kernel/sched/core.c`

```
#ifdef CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED
    /*
     * Do not allow realtime tasks into groups that have no runtime
     * assigned.
     */
    if (rt_bandwidth_enabled() && rt_policy(policy) &&
            task_group(p)->rt_bandwidth.rt_runtime == 0 &&
            !task_group_is_autogroup(task_group(p))) {
        task_rq_unlock(rq, p, &flags);
        return -EPERM;
    }
#endif
```

**PASS CASE** : Without `libpam-systemd`, I get the below values

```
[   36.278241] rt_bandwidth_enabled(): 1 
[   36.281977] rt_policy(policy) : 1 
[   36.285367] task_group_is_autogroup(task_group(p)) : 0 
[   36.289883] task_group(p)->rt_bandwidth.rt_runtime : 950000000
```

**FAIL CASE**: With `libpam-systemd`, I get the below values

```
[ 2096.713855] rt_bandwidth_enabled(): 1 
[ 2096.717871] rt_policy(policy) : 1 
[ 2096.721408] task_group_is_autogroup(task_group(p)) : 0 
[ 2096.726180] task_group(p)->rt_bandwidth.rt_runtime: 0
```

**QUESTION**: Why should libpam-systemd modify the rt runtime bandwidth for the root user ?

Scheduler RT runtime values from `proc`

```
root@jarvis:/home/jarvis# cat /proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_runtime_us 
950000
root@jarvis:/home/jarvis# cat /proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_period_us
1000000
```

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: A discussion on systemd mailing list regarding the same is @ http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2016-January/035674.html

Comment: Setting CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED=n solved this issue

Answer (score 5):

systemd creates a separate [cgroup](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/cgroup-v1) for each user and each service. Check `/proc/self/cgroup` to see the differences. Note that there are [known problems](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/README#L99-L106) with RT scheduling:

```
    We recommend to turn off Real-Time group scheduling in the
    kernel when using systemd. RT group scheduling effectively
    makes RT scheduling unavailable for most userspace, since it
    requires explicit assignment of RT budgets to each unit whose
    processes making use of RT. As there's no sensible way to
    assign these budgets automatically this cannot really be
    fixed, and it's best to disable group scheduling hence.
       CONFIG_RT_GROUP_SCHED=n
```